# Python Pandas apply booknames to id number?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A dataframe (df1) with a list of 20 book names and id numbers..

```
id, book
1,  name1
2,  name2
3,  name3
4,  name4
```

I want to take these id#'s and apply the book names to another larger table column which uses the same book id #s.

I've tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    df2[df2['id'] == row['id'], 'id'] = row['book']
```

Thank you

Comment: sounds like you like to merge the two DF based on the ID, if so then use pandas.merge. if you post DF2, someone will be able to show how to merge. Do include the expected result though

Comment: `df2.merge(df1, on='id')` or map: `df2['book'] = df2['id'].map(df1.set_index('id')['book'])`.